# Can an object containing an array be a type in an Interface's property?

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings

I'm analyzing an Angular code and I came across a `type` of a `property` of an `Interface` named 'Origin' that I don't understand?, Here it is:

```
export interface Origin {       
    areaNum?: number;  
    open?: { [key: string]: any };  
}
```

My first question is what kind of object is that? I thought `objects` had one or many  `key:value` pairs, where the `key` is.., well the key :), and the `value` can contain any value. This weird `type` seems to be an `object` but I don't see a `key:value`, it just contains an ¿`array`?. It seemed to me like if it was `array` because of the square brackets, but ¿can an array be the key of an `object`? how?. I'm trying to figure out how the property `open` would look like when creating an object that uses this `Interface`. I don't understand what is this `{ [key: string]: any };`.
Would you help me understand?, as I'm learning. If possible, may you show me a dummy example `object` that uses this `open` `property` with a valid `value` of the above weird `type`?. Thanks!

Comment: This means,  Open is optional, and its type is any object but, the key of object must be string, value can be anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My first question is what kind of object is that?

It's an object that has two optional properties:

- `areaNum`, a number
- `open`, an object using an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) allowing string indexes: the object can have properties with any string name, and the value of those properties is `any`

Here's a code example, see comments:

```typescript
export interface Origin {       
    areaNum?: number;  
    open?: { [key: string]: any };  
}

let a: Origin = {
    areaNum: 42,
    open: {}, // <== Valid, an index signature allows there to be no properties
};

if (a.open) {
    // You can do this, because `a.open` has an index signature making
    // any string is a valid property for it:
    a.open["any string you want"] = 42;
    // You *can't* do this, because `a` doesn't have an index signature,
    // it only has `areaNum` and `open` properties:
    a["any string you want"] = 42;
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgeSgQHNk4BvOK6uAKBsymEwDkBXAWwH4AuOJTgCM0Abir1qEMMCS8KcANoBrYAE8+AZxhEkxALp9MSVXAC+Yuqdq0ANsHiY+hEmQC8FCVUbN2HPgBYAJgAaTzgpGT5yU2C4AHo4uAAeV3cANUwbBAATWKNEJGzQOA0SJEwYNiY4TJsIAHcNOBgACzQ8GAg4YX4usCgI2ARgDVpzawR0OAAKTAA6CKQASg8aBLgATQg2OGx87K7WhA1Y4T22DTwAA3nFq7gWzCb85CKQErKKqrwOTCVkYhhdZGExaHTERDPOAAN0yOTg-UGMBM6GgiBgPDCt2kSAUACIQSVtAC4KptnB6kYYHi9HB3EEREDElsdgAqPZIADkMFZcAOzRax1OwHOlzgN3uBxGXPgj2heBehWKpWI5UqTFCa0SCHgECQNhMjyaNyYrE49yM2XFdwRA2kQxGmIY+MJYJJZJ2lJQNLpcAZY1oQA)